# Merge bisect-leftmost and bisect-rightmost to find the range of duplicates in sorted array

Tags: python

I am working to solve [Find First and Last Position of Element in Sorted Array - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-first-and-last-position-of-element-in-sorted-array/)

> 34. Find First and Last Position of Element in Sorted Array
>
> Medium
>
> Given an array of integers `nums` sorted in ascending order, find the starting and ending position of a given `target` value.
>
> Your algorithm's runtime complexity must be in the order of *O*(log *n*).
>
> If the target is not found in the array, return `[-1, -1]`.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 8
> Output: [3,4]
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 6
> Output: [-1,-1]
> ```

My solution is straightforward, `bisect-leftmost` and `bisect-rightmost`, then combine them

```
#leftmost solution 
class Solution:
    def searchRange(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        left = self.search_leftmost(nums, target)
        right = self.search_rightmost(nums, target)
        if left != len(nums) and right != len(nums) and nums[left] == nums[right] == target:
            return [left, right]
        else: return [-1, -1]

    def search_leftmost(self, nums, target) -> int:
        lo = 0
        hi = len(nums)
        while lo < hi:
            mid = (lo+hi) // 2
            if target > nums[mid]:
                lo = mid + 1
            else: 
                hi = mid 
        return lo 

    def search_rightmost(self, nums, target) -> int:
        lo = 0
        hi = len(nums)
        while lo < hi:
            mid = (lo+hi) // 2
            if target >= nums[mid]:
                lo = mid + 1
            else: 
                hi = mid
        return lo -1
```

Get the job done in two passes,
How could merge them together and solve the problem in one pass. since there are minor differences between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to simplify the code, you can only use `search_leftmost`, actually `search_rightmost(nums, target)` is kind of `search_leftmost(nums, target + 1) - 1`:

```
    def searchRange(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        left = self.search_leftmost(nums, target)
        right = self.search_leftmost(nums, target + 1) - 1
        # right = self.search_rightmost(nums, target)
        if left != len(nums) and right != len(nums) and nums[left] == nums[right] == target:
            return [left, right]
        else: return [-1, -1]
```

a more concise version is:

```
def searchRange(self, nums: 'List[int]', target: int) -> 'List[int]':
    left = self.search_leftmost(nums, target)
    right = self.search_leftmost(nums, target + 1) - 1
    return [left, right] if target in nums[left:left + 1] else [-1, -1]
```

Hope that helps you, and comment if you have further questions. : )